# Copy Just the Folder

Tags: directory, subdirectory, directory-structure, create-directory

I wanted to Copy just a single folder at a time from one location to another
Currently i hv to First go to the rename copy the name and come back to current location and create a new folder and paste the name

Just like TreeCopy Which copies folder complete structure
is there anything through which i can speed up this process and just generate a single folder from a 3000+ Collection of Folders

How can i copy just one folder from one location to another without copying anything inside it neither content nor sub folders.

if you know the way let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I know how hectic that work can get, but luckily there's an easy way around this.

Type in the following command in command prompt(cmd).

I think you need to have administrator rights for this.

```
xcopy “c:\users\cdwyer\documents\OriginalFolder” “c:\users\cdwyer\documents\NewFolder” /T /E
```

The command is **xcopy** and it takes two parameters, **the path of original folder** and **the path of new folder you want to create with the original folder structure.**

**/T** is just another parameter that ensures to only copy the folder structure, not the files.

**/E** is another parameter you can include to make sure empty folders are created.

If you have any other queries, just go through this website.

https://camerondwyer.com/2013/07/05/how-to-copy-an-entire-folder-structure-without-copying-the-files-tip-for-starting-the-new-financial-year/